# How to verify the user input in a textfield to compare it with a variable?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to verify the user input (number) in a `textfield` that if it's bigger than `9` or not. Note that the number from `1` to `9`.
if it's bigger than `9` I want to show a `jOptionPane` 
some code i have traied:

```
else
        if(jTextField1.contains()){ // want to compare it if it's bigger than 9 or not

            jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(this,"Please enter the number of the tab"); // wich means from 1 to 9
        }
```

So how to do that with java?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try it yourself and post some code. If you get struck, then we will help

Comment: @BhargavRao alright the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly do it with help of js using jQuery just give id to our text field and add a script tag with the following code :

```
num = $("#yourId").val();
if(num>9){
alert("your message");
}
```

or any thing else you want to achieve